# x64 CVTSD2SI instruction and REX.W

Tags: 64-bit, machine-code

Here is the instruction:

```
F2 REX.W 0F 2D /r CVTSD2SI r64, xmm/m64

Convert one double-precision floating-point 
value from xmm/m64 to one signed quadword 
integer sign-extended into r64.
```

How do I encode this?  The REX.W is what I'm having trouble with.  Do I just encode the opcode with a 0x48 or a 0x08?  So the opcode would look like this: F2, 48, 0F, 2D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the opcode would look like this: F2, 48, 0F, 2D?

Exactly. Just stick the arguments after it and it's good to go. For example:

```
cvtsd2si rax, xmm0  ; F2 48 0F 2D C0  (vex: C4 E1 FB 2D C0)
cvtsd2si r8, xmm0   ; F2 4C 0F 2D C0  (vex: C4 61 FB 2D C0)
```